# A characterization of wedges of 1-spheres and 2-spheres?

Tags: algebraic-topology

It is well known that if $X$ is a $1$-connected (i.e. path connected and simply connected) 2-dimensional finite simplicial complex, then $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of $2$-spheres.

Consider the more general setting where $X$ is path connected, and $\pi_1(X)$ is a free group. Is this enough to imply that $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of $1$-spheres and $2$-spheres?

Comment: Is the torus a counter-example? I'm not sure on this so please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: @AlexJBest: $\pi_1$ of a torus is a free *abelian* group, not a free group.

Comment: @Najib Of course, thanks :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is yes: if $X$ is a connected finite 2-dimensional CW-complex with $\pi_1(X)$ free, then $X$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of 1-spheres and 2-spheres. This is stated in the paragraph spanning the first and second pages of *Trees of Homotopy Types of Two-Dimensional CW-Complexes* by Dyer and Sieradski, available here:
http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02566109

Comment: The result itself is due to Whitehead.